# Universal links are not working in iOS 12

Tags: ios, ios12

I uploaded an app to the AppStore which supports universal links and is working perfectly without any issues in iOS 11.

Recently I updated my device OS to iOS 12 and downloaded this app from the AppStore. Universal links stopped working, which means it's taking me to the Safari page rather than my app.

I suspect iOS 12 is not calling the server to download the metadata.  I noticed the following logs in device console:

```
swcd(CoreUtils)[197] <Notice>: Added service 'applinks',
appID 'K5HKFCX9NG.com.example.test', domain 'example.test.com'

swcd(CoreUtils)[197] <Notice>: Skipping request for domain 
'example.test.com' when already outstanding
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't understand why iOS skip the above request. I think that is causing the issue.

Comment: Seems this issue resolved in iOS 12.1 beta. My App is working expected in iOS 12.1.

Comment: I have the same issue ! I don't know how we can resolve it !

Comment: @ali have you managed to find a solution ?